# Selecting 2 distinct fields but also return the rest of the columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, distinct

I want to distinctly select two fields of my table.

I do that using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `from`, `to` FROM `messages` WHERE `from`='9129771472' // the condition is just an example, any number could be there
```

The problem with that though, is that only `from` and `to` are selected. There are more columns that I will need to use.

I'm sure that there is a quick fix for this out there. I have looked at other posts about this, but nothing so far helped me.

Comment: Join this to a `SELECT` for the rest of the table.

Comment: If there's more than one row that shares a distinct `from, to` value, then any `DISTINCT` logic will require you to select only one of those rows and ignore the others. Do you have any requirements for *which* row to select when this happens?

Comment: @EdGibbs Thats the point. If there are distint `from, to` then it should only select one of them.

Comment: Right, but that means one or more other rows *won't* be selected. The answer from @dianuj below will do what you asked for, but it'll be more or less random which row is included and which row(s) are left out. If you're OK with that then you should be all set. If you have additional criteria just let us know. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the reason for not using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from`='9129771472' GROUP BY `from`
```

OR

```
    SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from`='9129771472' GROUP BY `from`,`to`
```

Comment: Because that doesn't give me distinct from and to fields. And it doesn't work like I want it. (:

Comment: This is now how you're supposed to use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @dianuj I have a `timestamp` column in my table and I would like to `order by timestamp DESC` before the `group by`. I have tried: `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from='9129771472' OR to='9129771472' ORDER BY timestamp DESC GROUP BY id` But that seems to throw an error. And I do have the ` in the correct places but I just had to remove them for the comment.